# downloading a .exe from chrome and discarding it

Tags: google-chrome, download, virus

hi i recently downloaded a file from the internet in .exe form and i thought there was something shifty about it so when you get the option about knowing the risk down the bottom of the browser i discarded it. is that all i need to do or is there follow up required. i have already tried to search in my download files and saw nothing however i was wondering if there were still traces. thanks

Comment: You indicated to Chrome you wanted to delete the file.  Why would Chrome keep the file despite the fact you choose the option to delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the file is removed (or in many cases not even downloaded to begin with).

Essentially chrome sends the url and some file metadata to google to check against known malicious downloads (file name and url).  If it's matched against something known, you're prompted before the download even starts.

If it (the URL and/or file name) doesn't match in their system, chrome may need to extract additional data about the file to send it and check again more in depth (I'm guessing this requires some download into a sandbox to get the files hash).

But on request to remove it's gone (this isn't documented, because it's doing what you asked).

The blog post on the update is [here](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/01/all-about-safe-browsing.html?m=1), but it only covers the high level overview, not some of my conjecture looking at a few source files quickly on mobile.